# $_POST[''] not working when using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

The `if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {` statement I'm using in my code stops working whenever I use JQuery on the same page.

Does anyone know why?

My full code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php if(isset($_GET['create_event'])) { 

        if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {

            echo "<script>alert('Works!');</script>";
        }
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name='submit_event' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Aanmaken</button>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This should alert with Works! but it doesn't. When I comment out the JQuery link it does work..

### UPDATE

I've tried the following:

`/agenda?create_event=1`

`<form method="POST" action='agenda.php?create_event=1'>`

New page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {
echo "<script>alert('Works!');</script>";
} ?>

<form method="POST">
<button type="submit" name='submit_event' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Aanmaken</button>
</form>
```

### UPDATE 2

I found out that the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`
 is what causes the issue. I just don't know why.

Full code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) { 
echo "<script>alert('Works!');</script>";
}
?>
    <form method="POST">
        Evenement Naam: <input type="text" name='ev_name'><br>
        Evenement Datum: <input type="date" name='ev_date'><br>
        Evenement Tijd: <input type="text" name='ev_time'><br>
        Evenement Informatie: <input type="text" name='ev_info'><br>
        Evenement Registratie Link: <input type="text" name='ev_link'><br>
        <button type="submit" name='submit_event' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Aanmaken</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: try to add a action parameter to the form with the url + `?create_event=1`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work @Oscargeek

Comment: i think that problem is the `$_GET['create_event']`, what's the url are you calling?

Comment: /agenda?create_event @Oscargeek

Comment: try with `/agenda?create_event=1`

Comment: Does not work either. I'll update my post with everything I've tried

Comment: Your update it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the condition `if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {` inside the `if(isset($_GET['create_event'])) {` .

**You can have like this**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {
echo 'This is Post Method';
        }
        if(isset($_GET['create_event'])) { 
echo 'This is Get Method';
        }
```

**Here the code you shall have like**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php if(isset($_GET['create_event'])) 
        { 
        echo "<script>alert('This is Get Method');</script>";
        }
        if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {

        echo "<script>alert('This is Post Method');</script>";    
        }
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name='submit_event' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Aanmaken</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

**For get Method :**

Just call the page like this for `get` method

`yourfile.php?create_event=1`

**For post Method :**

Just call the page from postman or any form or in any submit event with `method="post"` to get the `post` method

Comment: sorry but `GET` and `POST` can be inside in the same page without any problem. You can do a `<form action="index.php?action=1" method="POST">` and works.

Comment: @Oscargeek Then that will be the **POST** method only. You can see it from the `Network` tab in the console

Comment: Just giving the action as `action="index.php?action=1"` doesn't mean it was a `GET` method

Comment: no, if you try `<form action="index.php?action=1" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="variable" value="2" /></form>` in your PHP you will have one variable $_GET and one $_POST :)

Comment: @Oscargeek Cool ! That's the true :)

Comment: `Because GET and POST can't be inside the same page in same time.` this affirmation it's not true, if you remove it, i'll remove the negative

Comment: @Oscargeek Ah, I got your point now :) Agreed on your word ;)

Comment: Tried it using a whole new page, using only the POST method. It still does not work with JQuery included.

Comment: May i see the code that you have in your new page ?

Comment: Updated my post with the code of my new page @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: @ChrisDekker It shows me the alert `Works!` when i press the submit button. What is the your expectation here ?

Comment: @ChrisDekker What is the problem now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php if(isset($_GET['create_event'])) { 

      if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {

        echo "<script>alert('Works!');</script>";
      }
    }   
?>
<form method="POST" action="test.php?create_event=1">
<button type="submit" name='submit_event' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Aanmaken</button>
</form>
</div>
```